# Date/times from your SF Org into the MC will come over as GMT time

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We're looking for example AMPSCRIPT code that can help us convert our Event Objects STARTDATETIME field to the correct Day/Time. Thank you everyone!

The use case is that we have an email that notifies a client of a pending appointment scheduled by a sales rep. In some instances, the appointment is off one day as the timezone conversion is off 7 hours. The date is coming in as GMT. So the customer sees the appointment as happening the next day if the appointment is set to happen after 5pm MST.

```
%%[

/* AMPscript pulls in the values associated with the email subscriber from Salesforce */
SET @Id = [Event:WhoId] /* _subscriberkey is a system field */
/*SET @WhoId = Event:WhoId*/
/*SET @ClientRow = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Contact", "FirstName", "Id","=",@Id)*/

SET @FirstName = [Event:Who:Contact:FirstName] 
SET @StartDate = [Event:StartDateTime]
SET @ClientLocalStart = [Event:Client_Local_Start_Time__c]
SET @OwnerID = [Event:What:Opportunity:OwnerId]
SET @OwnerRow = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("User","NMLSNumber__c, Name, Phone, MobilePhone, FirstName, Fax, Email, Bio_Link__c", "Id","=",@OwnerId)

IF RowCount(@OwnerRow) > 0 THEN 

  SET @NMLSnumber = Field(Row(@OwnerRow,1),"NMLSNumber__c")
  /*SET @LOFirstName = Field(Row(@OwnerRow,1),"FirstName")*/
  SET @LOFullName = Field(Row(@OwnerRow,1),"Name")
  SET @LODirect = Field(Row(@OwnerRow,1),"Phone")
  SET @LOMobile = Field(Row(@OwnerRow,1),"MobilePhone")

  IF Length(@LOMobile) > 10 THEN
    SET @LOMobile = Substring(@LOMobile,4,10)
  ENDIF

  SET @LOFax = Field(Row(@OwnerRow,1),"Fax")
  SET @LOEmail = Field(Row(@OwnerRow,1),"Email")
  SET @LOBioLink = Field(Row(@OwnerRow,1),"Bio_Link__c")

ENDIF

]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DATEADD() function to modify the hours.  Display the @LocalDate in the email.

```
SET @TimeZoneModifier = -7
SET @LocalDate = DATEADD(@ClientLocalStart,@TimeZoneModifier,"H")
```